# People accessing older versions of our site?

Tags: apache, caching

Now this is going to sound a bit odd! For the last few months, we have seen errors coming up in our log files (I wrote a parser, that gives us a GUI interface to see the broken requests). Here is an example of one that came up just yesterday:

http://www.chambresdhotes.org/cgi-bin/links/jump.cgi?ID=141644

Its looking for:

http://www.chambresdhotes.org/Detailed/151969.html

I can't see **any** reference to `151969.html` on that page... so where on earth is it getting it from?

At first I thought it was just a random boo-boo by a spider, but its come from over 2000 different IPs in the last few months, which leads me to believe its something else.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Its driving me nuts! (we are doing changes to the site, yet we still get requests for old images on category pages, that were removed over 6 months ago!!!)

**UPDATE:** Another example:

Referal URL: http://www.chambresdhotes.org/
Requested: http://www.chambresdhotes.org/fr/apartment-verdun.html

This page is from 3+ years ago, so how on earth are people still seeing it (and clicking links on it). Here is the full log from it:

> 104.223.31.137 - - [16/Dec/2015:17:32:30 +0100] "GET /fr/apartment-verdun.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1858
>   "http://www.chambresdhotes.org/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64;
>   x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"

I am seeing quite a lot of similar IPs as well though:

> 104.223.31.179 - - [16/Dec/2015:17:32:30 +0100] "GET /fr/apartment-residence-raphael.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1858
>   "http://www.chambresdhotes.org/" "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64;
>   x64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"

Thanks

Comment: This sould be as simple as peoples old bookmarks being used

Comment: @RiggsFolly - they are using the *correct* urls though, with the correct referral - its just the requests that are being made that make no sense (for example, we changed our image storage from /images/1/foo.jpg, to images/0/1/12334-foo.jpg ...yet we are still seeing requests for the OLD stuff). Its very odd!